# Issue with StackEmptyException exception

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I'm having issues when compiling this for loop in my testing class.

In LabApp, the testing class, I currently have

```
import generics.StackFullException;
import generics.StackEmptyException;


public class Lab4App {
       public static void main(String[] args)throws StackFullException, StackEmptyException {
        try {
        DiscardPile<Card> discardPile = null; 
        discardPile = new DiscardPile<Card>();
        discardPile.push(new Card(8));
        discardPile.push(new Card(32));
        discardPile.push(new Card(48));
        discardPile.push(new Card(2));
        discardPile.push(new Card(17));
        discardPile.push(new Card(20)); //removeTopCard should remove all that's above
        discardPile.push(new Card(25));
        discardPile.push(new Card(50));
        discardPile.push(new Card(19));
        discardPile.push(new Card(41)); //10 Cards that must be popped

        for(int i = 0; i < discardPile.getSize(); i++) {
            Card var = discardPile.pop(); //pops the cards that are above
                System.out.println(var.getRankAsString() + " of " + var.getSuitAsString());
        }

        }
        catch (StackEmptyException SEE) {
            System.out.println("StackEmptyException: " + SEE.getMessage());
        }
        catch (StackFullException SFE) {
            System.out.println("StackFullException: " + SFE.getMessage());
       }
}
}
```

It's printing the desired output of

```
4 of Spades
8 of Diamonds
K of Spades
A of Diamonds
9 of Diamonds
6 of Diamonds
4 of Clubs
J of Spades
8 of Hearts
10 of Clubs
```

but it returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
```

in red at the end

I THINK the issue is the default constructor I created which is nearly identical to that of the Stack class, where pop, peek, and push are

```
public class DiscardPile<T> extends Stack<T>  { //subclass of its parent Stack
    private T[] data;
    private int size;


    //private static final int maxSize = 52;

    public DiscardPile() throws StackFullException, StackEmptyException {
        //this.data = (T[]) new Object[maxSize];
        this.size = 52; //52 is supposed to be the max value
    }
    /**
     * Constructs a new Stack with capacity specified by user
     * @param size the size of the Stack
     */
    public DiscardPile(int size){
        //this.data = (T[]) new Object[size];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public int getSize(){ // getter
        return this.size;
    }
```

If I input 10 instead of 52, it works just fine without an error at the end (since there are 10 Cards), if I input 0, it just doesn't print. Zero should be the initial value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
public class DiscardPile extends Stack implements Iterable {

```
//subclass of its parent Stack

    //private T[] data;
    private int size;


    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 52;

    public T push(T mink) {
        if (this.size() < this.MAX_SIZE) {
            super.push(mink);
        }
        return mink;
    }

    public DiscardPile() throws StackFullException, StackEmptyException {
        //this.data = (T[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE];
        this.size = 10; 
    }

    public DiscardPile(int size){
        //this.data = (T[]) new Object[size];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public int getSize(){ // getter
        return this.size;
    }
```

Comment: remove the size variable and use the `size()` function provided by Stack class

Comment: why did you extend `Stack`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko It has to be a subclass of stack for some reason

Comment: Remove the size variable completely and use size() instead of it

Comment: @AbdullahRazzaki Like this?                                                         public DiscardPile() throws StackFullException, StackEmptyException {
  this.data = (T[]) new Object[MAX_SIZE];
  this.size = getSize(); 
 }                                                                                                   It still doesn't print anything

Comment: @LostSoul I've updated my answer. I think that is all you need

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `getSize()` function to return the size, however the size is always hardcoded to `52` and this causes your `for` loop to try and pop more when nothing is available.

Why do you have a custom Class which implements `Stack<T>`? It doesn't seem to add much functionality.

If you want to keep using your custom class you can:

- use a for loop which keeps popping while `isEmpty()` is false.
- use the `size()` function which is located in the Stack class by default
- write something in your custom class which keeps track of the size when you add new items.

Comment: I was required to make this class (DiscardPile) into a subclass of Stack, hence why it is the way it is. It still doesn't work if I set it to size() or getSize().

Answer (score 1):

You should use `size()` function provided by the `Stack` class and if you want you enforce a max limit you can do something like

```
public class DiscardPile<T> extends Stack<T> {

private static int MAX_SIZE = 52;

public T push(T mink) {
    if (this.size() < this.MAX_SIZE) {
        super.push(mink);
    }
    return mink;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work. I wrote public T push(T elt) {
    if (this.size() < this.MAX_SIZE) {
        super.push(elt);
    }
    return elt;
}                                                                                       private static final int MAX_SIZE = 52;

Comment: It just doesn't print anything for the DiscardPile.push(); I'll update my post with what I have written at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Everyone pointed out the size issue. You can iterate through your custom Stack class. Implement Iterable interface

```
public class DiscardPile<T> extends Stack<T> implements Iterable<T> {

   @Override
   public Iterator<T> iterator() {
     return new Iterator<T>() {
         // Implementation your iterator, methods like hasNext etc.
     }
   }
}
```

Then Iterate through your stack

```
Iterator iterator = discardPile.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   //your code
}
```